# UINavigationController style in SingleViewApplication project

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to convert Single View application project which uses .xib (not storyboard) into `UINavigationController` style. I know about it using Storyboard which is very easy. But, i want to implement without storyboard. After I created a Single View application project, it comes with an `UIView` by default in a ViewController_XXX.xib. After that, how can i create root view controllers with it and make `UINavigationController` styles. Is there any tutorial somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create a NavigationController in `AppDelegate.h`

> @property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController
>   *navigationController;

1. edit AppDelegate.m

> -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
>
> ```
> UIViewController *rootController = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"nibfile name" bundle:nil];
>
> navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];
> [navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:5.84 saturation:0.05 brightness:0.02 alpha:0.0]];
> self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
> [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
> [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
> return YES;
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Reference from this [LINK](http://ioscoderef.blogspot.com/2012/08/adding-uinavigation-to-simple-view.html)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UINavigationController* navigationController =[[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

    [navigationController pushViewController:self.viewController animated:NO];

    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```